# Solving a cubic function with P and Q

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, cubics

I have been struggling a little bit over solving cubic functions. I have been trying to use the P and Q method.

So the question is

What is the approximate value of the greatest zero of $f(x) = x^3 - 6x^2 - x + 3$

So I got the $P's$: $\{1,-1,3,-3\}$ and the $Q's$: $1,-1$. Now I used the $\frac pq $and got this values: $\{1,-1,3,-3\}$ and started to use synthetic division to get a remainder of $0$. However, none of those values gave me a remainder of $0$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All that tells you is that there are no rational roots.  Doesn't mean there aren't real roots.

Comment: How would I get the roots if they are not rational?

Comment: Didn't ask you to find them, asked you to approximate them.  What techniques do you know?  You could graph the cubic...you could use Newton's method. There are closed formulas for solving cubic but they are unpleasant.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function)

Comment: A look at the cubic shows the biggest root is not much larger than $6$. That will give a good start for a numerical method.

Comment: I guess my best bet is to plug in generic values like -1,0,1 and hope I get close?

Comment: We don't know what techniques you know, so it is hard to advise.  As the comment of @AndréNicolas correctly remarks, we can see that $f(6)=-3$ and the function grows rapidly after that...so there is a real root just a bit bigger than $6$.  Newton's method is good from here.  Or just draw the tangent and take the intersection with the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Using Descartes rule of signs, there can be maximum two positive roots, and we observe the sign changes $f(0) = 3, f(6) = -3, f(7)=45$, so the largest root $\alpha \in (6, 7)$.

Writing $\alpha = 6+\epsilon$, we have $0< \epsilon < 1$, and we get $f(6+\epsilon) = -3+35\epsilon + 12\epsilon^2+\epsilon^3 = 0$.  Ignoring the cubic term, we get $\epsilon = \frac1{12}$, so $\alpha \approx 6\frac1{12}$ should be a good approximation.